# Xamarin ListView SimpleLineItem2 set datas

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I am working on a program and I would like to display a ListView with 2 lines (a Heading and a text) but the lines come from 2 different string[]

how can I do that ? Here is my code right now (I only have one line)

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    Button addATaskButton;

    ListView listeView;
    View view;
    Activity context;
    private List<string> titres = new List<string>();
    private List<string> textes = new List<string>();
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        addATaskButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.AddATaskButton);
        listeView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listeTasks);
        ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(ApplicationContext);
        ISet<string> listeTitresTaches = new HashSet<string>(prefs.GetStringSet("Titres", new HashSet<string>()));

        ISet<string> listeTextesTaches = new HashSet<string>(prefs.GetStringSet("Textes", new HashSet<string>()));


        foreach (string items in listeTitresTaches)
        {
            titres.Add(items);
        }
        foreach (string items2 in listeTextesTaches)
        {
            textes.Add(items2);
        }



        //view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem2, null);

        var ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem2, titres.ToArray());

        listeView.Adapter = ListAdapter;





        addATaskButton.Click += delegate
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(AddTaskActivity));
        };
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to display a ListView with 2 lines

`SimpleAdapter` should be suitable for you.

Try the following code:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    ListView lv;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        lv = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, getData(),Resource.Layout.ListViewItem,
           new string[] { "textView1", "textView2" },
           new int[] { Resource.Id.textView1, Resource.Id.textView2});
        lv.Adapter = adapter;
    }

    public List<IDictionary<string, object>> getData()
    {

        List<IDictionary<string, object>> list = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var item1 = new JavaDictionary<string, object>();
            item1.Add("textView1", "Title Mike Ma");
            item1.Add("textView2", "Body Mike Ma");
            list.Add(item1);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

screen shot:

[image]